# How to compare two files to see if they are the same?

Tags: java, file-handling, fileinputstream

I used to think that I can use the checksum (MD5 or CRC32) to improve the uploading method. That is, if the files checksum is the same, I think it's the same file. But one day I saw the code in `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` which contains two method `contentEquals` and `contentEqualsIgnoreEOL`. There are two way to check the same file.

```
if (file1.getCanonicalFile().equals(file2.getCanonicalFile())) {  
        // same file  
        return true;  
    }
```

and

```
IOUtils.contentEquals(new FileInputStream(f1), new FileInputStream(f2));
```

Here are what confused me.

- I can't get enough information about the `canonical`. What's this meaning?
- it use the IO stream to check the file instead of the checksum.

So, in which situation should I use the bytes or checksums to check the same file.

Comment: MD5 can, in certain circumstances, be subject to collisions. However, for most cases it is fine. For better collision avoidance, you can use other hashing systems. We use checksums in all of our file transfers, as it is nice to be able to send a checksum along with a file, and allow independent verification on a remote system.

Comment: (1) It's resolving the real location of the file path; if you pass two files that are symlinks to the same file there is no point in testing further. They're the same real file. (2) To compute the MD5 or the CRC32 you must read both files and perform math. If you're reading both anyway, you might as well read them in lockstep and compare as you go. That has the advantage that it can short circuit at the first difference (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first one checks the file path to see if both the file refers to the same file.
2. The second on check the complete file to see if the content of the file is the same.

**Checksum**

1. If two checksum are different you can say with confidence that the files are different.
2. If the two checksum are equal you can not say with confidence that the files are same.

Checksum can be used to do quick check by caching the Checksum of each file upfront.